# How to disable dropdown while selecting 1st or 2nd dropdown vice verse

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4, angular6, angular7, dropdown

I have 2 dropdowns.

I'm populating those with product code(1st dropdown) and product name(2nd dropdown).I need to disable dropdown based on selection. suppose I selected 1st dropdown then disable 2nd dropdown. same vice versa selected 2nd dropdown then need to disable 1st dropdown.

```
<select id="Code" class="form-control" placeholder="Code"

   disabled="stockForm.get('productName')?.value"

    formControlName="productId" required>
    <option [value]="''">Select Code</option>
    <option [value]="product.productId"
        *ngFor="let product of productData">
        {{product.sku}}
    </option>
</select>

 <select id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"
   disabled="stockForm.get('productId')?.value"
   formControlName="productName" required>
    <option [value]="''">Select Name</option>
    <option [value]="product.productName"
        *ngFor="let product of productData">
        {{product.productName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code given below is what you need,If the user select the chose option again all the drop down will get enabled so that they can re-select the other drop-down option.

**Two way data binding ([(disabled)]="productNameSelected") is used to do this.**

[Refer this](https://www.javatpoint.com/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-8)

**HTML :**

```
<select id='selectProductCode' (change)="productCodeChanged($event)" [(disabled)]="productNameSelected" >
    <option value="0">Choose code </option>
    <option value="1">Code1</option>
    <option value="2">Code2</option>
 </select>
 <select id='selectProductName' (change)="produvtNameChanged($event)" [(disabled)]="productCodeSelected" >
    <option value="0">Choose name </option>
    <option value="1">Name1</option>
    <option value="2">Name 2</option>
</select>
```

**Type Script :**

```
productCodeSelected: boolean = false;
productNameSelected: boolean = false;
productCodeChanged(args) {
var value = args.target.value;
if (value > 0) {
  this.productCodeSelected = true;
}
else {
  this.productCodeSelected = false;
 }
}

produvtNameChanged(args) {
 var value = args.target.value;
 if (value > 0) {
  this.productNameSelected = true;
}
else {
  this.productNameSelected = false;
 }
}
```